# Parsing Email To Header

Tags: c#, regex

Ok so I am currently facing a few difficulties with my email parser

When I started, most of the emails I tested with was something like the following

`"name@domain.co.za,  othername@domain.co.za"` this I can easilly split by the comma, but I get the following cases that doesn't work

1) `"\"Surname, Name, Company Country\" <name.surname@domain.co.za>"`

With that I tried the following

`Regex.Split(Headers["to"] ?? "", "(?<=@\\S*)\\s+");`

But that doesn't remove the comma then so I am using .Trim(',') to remove the trailing comma then some cases work

Example that works
`"name@domain.co.za,  othername@domain.co.za"`

For example the following doesn't work

2) `"\"Name Surname <name@domain.co.za>\" <name@domain.co.za>"`

I also tried to use `Regex.Split(Headers["to"] ?? "", ",(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)");`
 But it fails in a situation like the following

`"\"Name Surname\" <Name@domain.co.za>, \"Name Surname\" <Othername@domain.co.za>"`

Now using a new Regex `(?:""([^""]+)"")?\s*<?\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\b` it is quite close, using the following exaple I get the following output

Input: `"\"Donald Jansen\" <Donald@peachss.co.za>, \"Donald Jansen\" <djhabana@gmail.com>"`
Output

```
"\"Donald Jansen\" <Donald@peachss.co.za
\"Donald Jansen\" <djhabana@gmail.com
```

So it ignored the trailing `>`, I fixed this by adding `>?` to the regex and I also found a new scenario that is not working, so the regex is now `(?:"([^"]+)")?\s*<?\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\b>?`

```
"name <name@xxx.co.za>, name name <name@xxx.co.za>, name <name@xxx.co.za>, \"'name'\" <name@xxx.com>"
```

The output now is

`<name@xxx.co.za> << not correct name is needed`

`<name@xxx.co.za> << not correct name is needed`

`<name@xxx.co.za> << not correct name is needed`

`\"'name'\" <name@xxx.com>" << this is correct`

Comment: Can't you match all those with something like [`@"\b\S+@\S+\.\S+\b"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cS%2b%40%5cS%2b%5c.%5cS%2b%5cb&i=name%40domain.co.za%2c++othername%40domain.co.za+%22Surname%2c+Name%2c+Company+Country%22+%3cname.surname%40domain.co.za%3e+%22Name+Surname%22+%3cName%40domain.co.za%3e%2c+%22Name+Surname%22+%3cOthername%40domain.co.za%3e)?

Comment: Its working the same as the other answers, its a start but I would love to get the part "\"Name Surname\" with <Name@domain.co.za>

Comment: What is the pattern then? `"` + 1+ chars other than `"` + `"`  + `spaces` + `email`? Try [`(?:"([^"]+)")?\s*<?\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%22%28%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%29%22%29%3f%5cs*%3c%3f%5cb%28%5cS%2b%40%5cS%2b%5c.%5cS%2b%29%5cb&i=name%40domain.co.za%0d%0aothername%40domain.co.za%0d%0a%22Surname%2c+Name%2c+Company+Country%22+%3cname.surname%40domain.co.za%3e+%0d%0a%22Name+Surname%22+%3cName%40domain.co.za%3e%2c+%0d%0a%22Name+Surname%22+%3cOthername%40domain.co.za%3e)

Comment: Please check [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%22%28%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%29%22%29%3f%5cs*%3c%3f%5cb%28%5cS%2b%40%5cS%2b%5c.%5cS%2b%29%5cb&i=name%40domain.co.za%0d%0aothername%40domain.co.za%0d%0a%22Surname%2c+Name%2c+Company+Country%22+%3cname.surname%40domain.co.za%3e+%0d%0a%22Name+Surname%22+%3cName%40domain.co.za%3e%2c+%0d%0a%22Name+Surname%22+%3cOthername%40domain.co.za%3e).

Comment: There is a few patterns "name" <email> , "name" <email>
then the one unique one is like (1) in my question
"xxx, xxx, xxx" <email>, "xxx" <email>

Comment: The demo is really close :) just need the last `>' thanks for the help so far

Comment: What do you mean by "just need the last `>`"? Please update the question with sample input-expected output.

Comment: Make your life easier. All of the emails are separated by a comma, regardless if they contain just the email or the name and the email. Split on , and use a simplified regex to pull the email address and the name out.

OR better still, don't reinvent the wheel. There's already a solid library that does the heavy lifting for you: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit
If it's an option, it's worth considering using.

Comment: @Kushan check this email `"\"Surname, Name, Company Country\" <name.surname@domain.co.za>"` Split by comma

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my question, thanks for your help so far, atleas getting somewhere

Comment: Managed to get it to work with Regex `((\w+[ ])|\"(.*?)\"+[ ])+(<?\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\b>)|(\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)` Played a bit on the website http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick to find all valid emails in the string.

```
Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(data);
foreach (Match emailMatch in emailMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(emailMatch.Value);
}
```

Comment: I wonder what you used the case ignoring flag for. Your regex does not contain letters.

Comment: This is work great! but I want to get the names aswell (if any) as like in the following case "\"Name Surname\" <Name@domain.co.za>, \"Name Surname\" <Othername@domain.co.za>"

Comment: Once you got the valid emails. You can read something before `<` or some sort of logic can be build. I am not sure.

Comment: Hey!! who is the angry downvoter. Lemme know the reason. It serves what OP wanted.

Comment: Whoever down voted did so unnecessary, this is already a lot closer to what I need

Comment: @MohitShrivastava not all cases have `<` but I will give it a try

Comment: may be you can read an email from all emails and see if the string contains any valid alphabets before you get any other `co.za` using `IndexOf`if yes then it might have names associated with the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Email Regex' from [emailregex.com](http://emailregex.com/)

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Comment: This works the same as Mohit, just extracts the emails and ignoring the names

Comment: emailregex.com is a terrible idea and completely out of date. Many of the new TLD's do not validate using this regex. Try typing in a .rocks or .yoga email address and it'll say it's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help that @MohitShrivastava and @WiktorStribiżew I managed to build my own regex using a combination of their regex that they provided, it is probably not optimized and a bit ugly but it is working as I expect it to

`((\w+[ ])|\"(.*?)\"+[ ])+(<?\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\b>)|(\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)`

Sample code

```
            var emailRegex = new Regex(@"((\w+[ ])|\""(.*?)\""+[ ])+(<?\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\b>)|(\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(Headers["to"]);
            foreach (Match emailMatch in emailMatches)
            {
                try
                {
                    To.Add(new MailAddress(emailMatch.Value));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```